# How to Style Unique CSS Navigation Menu

Tags: css, navigation

I have a fair amount of CSS knowledge, but I've been stumped while trying to achieve a unique navigation bar for a website I'm working on.

Since pictures are worth over 9000 words, I put together a diagram to represent the scenario.

[image: Diagram]

The #container (blue) is 1000px wide and has 25px rounded corners. At the top of the container is the #navbar (green) which is the full width of the #container and is 55px high (it matches the top, left, and right edges of the #container, but I enlarged it in the image so you could see it better). Inside of the #navbar are the different navigation buttons (red). I want all of the buttons to be equally wide (and always stretch from one side to the other), and the buttons on the far left/right to have rounded corners like the grandparent #container. The solution need to be pure and strict CSS and work across most modern browsers (except IE 8 and under).

I want this to be a learning experience, so if you post the code, please provide some explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</nav>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

You should probably turn that into a list...

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    display: table; /* see below */
    width: 1000px;
}
#container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1000px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px; /* top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left */
}
nav span {
    display: table-cell; /* spreads them equally across, no matter how many elements */
    height: 55px;
    background: green;
}
nav span:first-child {
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
}
nav span:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHVSZ/

Comment: Perfect. `display: table;` is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Do note, IE7 does not support `display: table`. But that doesn't seem to effect you, since you're only interested in IE9 & above.

Comment: I'd love a solution that works for IE7 as well, but frankly I'm tired of catering  to the needs of the ignorant. `border-radius` doesn't work until IE9 either, but anyone still using IE8 can deal with their straight corners. ;)

Comment: I've got one more question, if you're up for it: how can I modify this so that the entire span is a link as opposed to just the text?

Answer (score 2):

**updated:**

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jQpF8/4/

is this what you need?

to set equal widths, you should manually set the widths using percentages (total width of nav bar/no. of links) of the links or set it via JS in case of dynamically changing number of links.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have only 3 Items, you can give width of 33% to first 2 of them, and auto to the 3rd - so they are stretched to the end, also adding 2 classes - "first-item" on first menuitem and "last-item" on the last, so you can give them border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius